# Desabilitar as datas anteriores datapicker com bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datapicker

Colegas.

Através [do site](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&autoclose=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on&datesDisabled=on#sandbox), implementei o datapicker no meu sistema, porém gostaria de desabilitar as datas anteriores da data atual. Pelo modelo deles, apresenta a seguinte forma:

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    datesDisabled: ['02/06/2016']
});
```

Notem que desabilitar apenas a data 02/06/2016. Como eu faria para desabilitar as datas anteriores antes da data atual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

Veja funcionando aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/191c5apr/1/

Comment: Certo... podemos usar também o startDate: "date", mas mesmo assim obrigado pela sua ajuda Berriel

Comment: @Jose.Marcos verdade, também é possível...